# Using the variable of .aspx code in .js code

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, asp.net

I have one variable in `.aspx` code and i want to use it in my `.js` code.

How to make this work?

In .aspx code..

```
var url = document.referrer;
var res = url.split("?");
var str = res[1];
```

So I want the str to be used in my .js code..

Comment: What is that variable? Can you please share the snippet?

Comment: Use session or viewstate.

Comment: where does your .js file locate? in .aspx file?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor .js is a different file in visual studio

Comment: So where have you referred it? I mean where did you give script tag?

Comment: there are two .aspx file. default.aspx and I have added one app part. So .js has been referenced in default.aspx and i have a variable in AppPart.aspx. So now i want to use that variable in .js file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code is not ASPX code. It is JavaScript code (inside a Script block in your ASPX file?)

If it is not a Global variable yet, you can declare it as `window.js=res[1]` to force it in the global scope (and thus available to all other functions)

Time to read about Javascript Variables, Closures etc. :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
- http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/